# Simultaneous Subset sums

Tags: dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I am dealing with a problem which is a variant of a subset-sum problem, and I am hoping that the additional constraint could make it easier to solve than the classical subset-sum problem.  I have searched for a problem with this constraint but I have been unable to find a good example with an appropriate algorithm either on StackOverflow or through googling elsewhere.

The problem:

Assume you have two lists of positive numbers A1,A2,A3... and B1,B2,B3... with the same number of elements N.  There are two sums Sa and Sb.  The problem is to find the simultaneous set Q where |sum (A{Q}) - Sa| <= epsilon and |sum (B{Q}) - Sb| <= epsilon.  So, if Q is {1, 5, 7} then A1 + A5 + A7 - Sa <= epsilon and B1 + B5 + B7 - Sb <= epsilon.  Epsilon is an arbitrarily small positive constant.

Now, I could solve this as two completely separate subset sum problems, but removing the simultaneity constraint results in the possibility of erroneous solutions (where Qa != Qb).  I also suspect that the additional constraint should make this problem easier than the two NP complete problems.  I would like to solve an instance with 18+ elements in both lists of numbers, and most subset-sum algorithms have a long run time with this number of elements.  I have investigated the pseudo-polynomial run time dynamic programming algorithm, but this has the problems that a) the speed relies on a short bit-depth of the list of numbers (which does not necessarily apply to my instance) and b) it does not take into account the simultaneity constraint.

Any advice on how to use the simultaneity constraint to reduce the run time?  Is there a dynamic programming approach I could use to take into account this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description of the problem correctly (I'm confused about why you have the distance symbols around "sum (A{Q}) - Sa" and "sum (B{Q}) - Sb", it doesn't seem to fit the rest of the explanation), then it is in NP.

You can see this by making a reduction from Subset sum (SUB) to Simultaneous subset sum (SIMSUB).
If you have a SUB problem consisting of a set X = {x1,x2,...,xn} and a target called t and you have an algorithm that solves SIMSUB when given two sets A = {a1,a2,...,an} and B = {b1,b2,...,bn}, two intergers Sa and Sb and a value for epsilon then we can solve SUB like this:
Let A = X and let B be a set of length n consisting of only 0's. Set Sa = t, Sb = 0 and epsilon = 0. You can now run the SIMSUB algorithm on this problem and get the solution to your SUB problem. 
This shows that SUBSIM is as least as hard as SUB and therefore in NP.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  However, I do not think that this answer is correct.  Setting all the parameters in the second set to zero is effectively removing the constraint.  Yes, that would reduce to SUB.  However, the constraint adds specificity, in the same manner as adding an equation to a set of linear equations, so getting rid of it should make the problem harder, not easier.  Thus, I do not follow your logic that SUBSIM is at least as hard as SUB.  It is good logic for showing that it is at least as easy as SUB.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the | | symbols are absolute value in this case.

Comment: I understood that it was absolute value, yes, I just failed to see why, but I do now.

Comment: Adding constraints does not necessarily make a problem easier. There might be problems with my reduction, and you are most likely better to spot them than I as your are more into the problem, but if there are not, then I'm positive that I am correct. If you can use the algorithm for SIMSUB to solve SUB, and SIMSUB is easier than SUB, then SUB is easier than SUB, which does not make sense.

Comment: I just wanted to add, in case you are not used to my type of arguing: If you have a problem, A (SUB), that is known to be in NP, and you are able to transform (reduce) it into another problem B (SIMSUM) using only polynomial time (in this case linear time), then you have proved that the problem B is also in NP. This is the standard way of proving that a problem is in NP. If you think about it it makes perfect sense, as being able to solve B fast implies being able to solve A fast as we can just transform it into a B problem and then solve it. Hence my claim that SIMSUM is at least hard as SUB.